# parent of a node in a binary tree by searching given key

Tags: binary-tree, binary-search-tree

this is the function in c that's not giving me the solution

```
 struct node* serch(struct node *ptr,int x)

 {

   if(ptr->data==x)
   {     
     printf(" root of tree itself ");
   }
   else
   {     
     struct node *ptr1,*ptr2;
     ptr1=ptr->left;
     ptr2=ptr->right;

     while((ptr1->data!=x)&&(ptr2->data!=x))
     {
         if(ptr->data>x)
         {
             ptr=ptr1;
             ptr1=ptr->left;
             ptr2=ptr->right;
         }

         else if(ptr->data<x)
         {
             ptr=ptr2;
             ptr1=ptr->left;
             ptr2=ptr->right;
         }
     }
     return ptr;
   }
 }
```

THE code works fine for the node's having both the children(particularly works fine upto the level the tree is balanced) but after that it doesn't work and gives the error

parentnode.exe has stopped working ,windows is checking for a solution.

Comment: @Mark Lakata , even after fixing the first bug,i am not getting through and it would be very generous of you if you give the code snippet to fix the second bug as i am not able to fix it myself.

Comment: Ask yourself, what happens if a node doesn't have a left foot? or a right foot? or neither?  Sorry, I can't help any more than that. Ask your teacher.

Answer (score 0):

You have several bugs

1. you are not returning something for the case `ptr->data==x`. Your c compiler should have given a warning that not all paths return a value.
2. you are not checking for nulls